# Debugging pytorch code in pycharm (Feasibility)

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pytorch

I am trying to run a code in written in python (pytorch code) which when passed as an arguments options trains the Neural network.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    myparams = args["options"]
    ....
    /* do work */
```

Now if we have to run this code, I need to call it from console. `python3 train.py --option1 123` etc. But in that case the debug points won't work in pycharm. Can anybody clarify how to debug in this scenario? (If you know the way it would be great if you let me know).

Answer (score 1):

Look at menu bar,Run->Edit Configurations->(Chose One Configuration)Parameters